# "Unable to locate element" error when reading data from a table, with 3/10 reproduction rate

Tags: java, selenium

I have written the code below for getting the data from a column:

```
String[] correct = new String[101];
        String a = "//*[@id='mainData']/table/tbody/tr[";
        String b = "]/td[2]";
        int[] comparison = new int[101];
        for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
            String c = a + i + b;
            WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(c));
            correct[i] = element.getText();
            if (correct[i].equals("Order Request Import")) {
                String[] orderButton = new String[101];
                String e = "//*[@id='mainData']/table/tbody/tr[";
                String f = "]/td[1]/div/button";
                String g = e + i + f;
                orderButton[i] = driver.findElement(By.xpath(g)).getText();
                comparison[i]=Integer.parseInt(orderButton[i].substring(4));
            }
        }
```

The problem is that 3 out of 10 tests are failing at line `WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(c));`, while the rest are working like a charm. Any idea why this occurs, or how to improve my code so it reads from the table all the time?

Comment: How does it fail?  What is the error message?

Comment: Can you share a link or html source? Why are you starting your loop from 1 instead of 0? The first index of your 'correct' array will be unused. Are you using the 'correct' away after the code you have shown. If not use a variable. What is the use of the 'orderButton' array defined for size 100 when you only put in one string and throw it away after the if condition. Use a variable.

Comment: @Breaks it's "Unable to locate element" error message, at the line `WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(c));`, just said it above

Comment: @Grasshopper the arrays are inside a for loop, iterating all results from the column...so i need the array to store all 100 results. IF i start my loop at 0, i get the "Unable to locate element" error 10/10, the div[0]/div[2] element does not exist on my page, first element from table is div[1]/div[2].

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible when you are going to locate element, it would not be present on the `DOM`, that's why your test becomes fail some time.

For better way you should implement [`WebDriverWait`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html) here to wait until element present on the `DOM` then do the next operation as below :-

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);

WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath(c)));
```

Comment: Oh, that is the line above the first line posted here :)) it goes like this:
`new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id='mainData']/div[1]/div/button")));
  String[] correct = new String[101];`.and so on with the code posted above.

So, other solutions?:D

Comment: @Tudor you need to implement `ExpectedConditions` for this element as well...for better way you should always find every element using `ExpectedConditions`...:)

Comment: If you are waiting for one element that's does not mean you would not wait for other element as well, you should find every element with explicit wait..:)

Comment: Could you please give me an example on the above code on how to find the element with expected conditions?

Comment: You just Initialize Once WebDriverWait in your  script and use this reference to find element with ExpectedConditions...:)

Comment: So basically wait.until behaves like driver.findelement? like, in your example above, if i then write "element.click()" that is going to work? Thanks man!!

Comment: Actually `ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated` works like `driver.findelement`, and `wait.until` wait with given `ExpectedConditions` if the condition becomes try it returns that `WebElement`. So after that you can use `element.click()`..:)